# Menu style not working like I expect it to

Tags: asp.net, css

So I'm trying to put a menu in my website and I'm having trouble getting the sub menu items to have smaller text than the first menu item. Here's my code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="subMenuStyle" />
        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <LevelSubMenuStyles>
            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="masterBannerMenu" />
        </LevelSubMenuStyles>
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="WHERE I'VE BEEN" NavigateUrl="~/whereivebeen.aspx">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="UNESCO Sites" NavigateUrl="~/unesco.aspx" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Places" NavigateUrl="~/BlogPosts.aspx" />
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<a href="#Menu1_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/TravelJoansBlog/WebResource.axd?d=i8kPrDg0W2gPsNdgiFoKNbdLkjHOBO6T-YtC_Usb-id70m3Q7jX8wpftWKKoZFCuuiThX_JLEnw1KCG7FBKqB3_JiRZTcYRUnLGsCYCvOwo1&amp;t=634970873020000000" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div id="Menu1">
    <ul class="level1 masterBannerMenu">
    <li><a class="popout level1 subMenuStyle" href="whereivebeen.aspx">WHERE I'VE BEEN</a><ul class="level2">
        <li><a class="level2" href="unesco.aspx">UNESCO Sites</a></li><li><a class="level2" href="BlogPosts.aspx">Places</a></li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
.masterBannerMenu a
    {
        font-family:"Century Gothic";
        font-size: 16pt;
        width: auto;
        text-align: left;  
        color: Black;
        text-decoration: none;   
    }
    .subMenuStyle a
    {
        font-family:"Century Gothic";
        font-size: 12pt;
        width: auto;
        text-align: left;  
        color: Black;
        text-decoration: none;   
    }
```

Only what is in the SubMenuStyles element ever gets applied. I've tried switching the two CSS classes, setting the font size in the asp:Menu control and then applying CSS styles, and I've had no luck. Again, I'm trying to get my sub menu item text (UNESCO Sites and Places) to be smaller than the first level menu (WHERE I'VE BEEN)

Comment: And yes, the two CSS classes have different sizes for the text

Comment: Consider editing the question to show us the actual rendered html and the relevant css.

Comment: nesting a `<ul>` inside `<li>` is not valid HTML and probably the majority of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alter your .NET markup and/or code-behind to make it generate HTML similar to:

```
<a href="#Menu1_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/TravelJoansBlog/WebResource.axd?d=i8kPrDg0W2gPsNdgiFoKNbdLkjHOBO6T-YtC_Usb-id70m3Q7jX8wpftWKKoZFCuuiThX_JLEnw1KCG7FBKqB3_JiRZTcYRUnLGsCYCvOwo1&amp;t=634970873020000000" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
<div id="Menu1">
    <ul class="level1 masterBannerMenu">
        <li><a class="popout level1 subMenuStyle" href="whereivebeen.aspx">WHERE I'VE BEEN</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="level2">
        <li><a class="level2" href="unesco.aspx">UNESCO Sites</a></li><li><a class="level2" href="BlogPosts.aspx">Places</a></li>
    </ul>
```

See the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8uetJ/)

Comment: That can probably be a blanket statement for `<asp:*>` controls.

Comment: Since these are not using database to populate their values, should I just be able to use the HTML? It seems I would?

Comment: Oh, absolutely. If you can use good ol' fashioned HTML to get your job accomplished vs. any of the `<asp:>` controls, do it. Keep it simple.

Comment: I'm confused on how to make level2 items popout when hovered over.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to show below "WHERE I'VE BEEN" and no text decoration

Comment: Let's continue this [in a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37848/menu-style-not-working-like-i-expect-it)